# Bootstrap drop down does not work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to accomplish a simple drop down using the bootstrap example, but it does not respond to anything when I click it. I have searched on this problem and none of the solutions helped me (i.e. putting the links to the resources in head, or at different order). Don't mind the angular code

Here is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- express style that I like-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
    <title>Pharmpool NIH | Express</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="nihApp">

    <h1>PharmPool on nih Express</h1>
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="MainController">

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Dropdown
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery and Angular -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script type="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angular code[controller] -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks, Alon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one thing in your script tag that is `type="text/javascript"`.

That's why the `dropdown` is not working..

Your Script tag.

```
<script type="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It should be like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```